# Extract value form XML

Tags: php, xml

i just have problems with extract data from XML.

Content looks like this:

```
  <entry>
    <id>tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-227841964192642355.post-8872593151327492602</id>
    <published>2016-08-15T01:56:00.001-07:00</published>
    <updated>2016-08-15T01:56:36.304-07:00</updated>
    <title type='text'>Podaj tytuł wpisu spintax</title>
    <content type='html'>Treść wpisu spintax </content>
    <link rel='replies' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://ecookingwithme.blogspot.com/feeds/8872593151327492602/comments/default' title='Komentarze do posta' />
    <link rel='replies' type='text/html' href='http://ecookingwithme.blogspot.com/2016/08/podaj-tytu-wpisu-spintax.html#comment-form' title='Komentarze (0)' />
    <link rel='edit' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://www.blogger.com/feeds/227841964192642355/posts/default/8872593151327492602' />
    <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://www.blogger.com/feeds/227841964192642355/posts/default/8872593151327492602' />
    <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='I NEED THIS LINK' title='Podaj tytuł wpisu  spintax' />
    <author>
      <name>NAMEa</name>
      <uri>link here</uri>
      <email>noreply@blogger.com</email>
      <gd:image rel='link here' width='16' height='16' src='link here' />
    </author>
    <thr:total>0</thr:total>
  </entry>
```

Ho to extract data form     `<link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='I NEED THIS LINK' title='Podaj tytuł wpisu  spintax' />`
 ?

I dont know how to extract this, i can easy extract title but i dont know how to do the same with LINK alternate, thanks for advice.

Here is what i have write:

```
$file = "http://ecookingwithme.blogspot.com/atom.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
echo $xml->entry->title;
```

Also i have try with:

```
$file = "http://ecookingwithme.blogspot.com/atom.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);

foreach ( $xml->entry as $foo ) {
    foreach ( $foo->link as $link ) {
        $type = (string) $link->attributes()->{'rel'};
        if ( $type == 'rel' ) {
            echo (string) $link->attributes()->{'href'};
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are already in the `entry` element so just loop through the `link`s and you can get the `href`.

```
$sxml = new simplexmlelement($xml);
foreach($sxml->link as $link) {
     if($link['rel'] == 'alternate') {
          echo $link['href'];
     }
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/622605

Answer (score 0):

Not using `simple_xml` but regular `DOMDocument` you can do this in a few lines of code

```
$file='http://ecookingwithme.blogspot.com/atom.xml';

$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->load( $file );

$col=$dom->getElementsByTagName('link');
foreach( $col as $node ) echo $node->getAttribute('href').'<br />';
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're using `simple_xml` you might consider using its XPath functionality to extract the nodes you need:

```
$file = "http://ecookingwithme.blogspot.com/atom.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);

$links = $xml -> Xpath("//link/@href");
```

The above XPath will extract every link, if you need it to be more specific you would edit the XPath statement.