# Put something in article in random place with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to put random text in an article so I use `explode` to make every word an array:

```
$article = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec lectus urna, tempor nec dui eget, ullamcorper interdum ex. Sed velit velit, sodales non eros eu, porttitor ultricies risus. Morbi semper ultrices tortor non vestibulum. Vestibulum eu lorem odio. Duis placerat dapibus lorem sit amet viverra. Nam at sagittis augue, sit amet interdum metus. Curabitur quis diam pellentesque, auctor magna eget, cursus orci. Proin et fringilla mi. Vivamus egestas sed turpis vel scelerisque. Proin sit amet commodo urna, vel pulvinar lacus. Praesent tincidunt ut diam at interdum.';

$words = explode(' ', $article);
// a new array to hold the string we are going to create
$newString = array();
// loop all words of the original string
foreach ($words as $i => $w) {
    // add every word to the new string
    $newString[] = $w;
}

$inserted = array('ad this in random place'); // Not necessarily an array
$ilejest = count($newString); // count all words from array 
$wstawwloowo = rand(1, $ilejest); // random number from 1 to max number of values in array
$newString = array_splice( $newString, $wstawwloowo, 0, $inserted ); //

// create a string from the array of words we just composed
$contenttre = implode(' ', $newString);
```

How to make it works?

Comment: You could say that is what does not works?

Comment: yes i get blank page when i test this any output...

Comment: `$words` and  `$newString` are identical arrays, i dont know why you created the latter

Comment: Well, you didn't output anything, what do expect to see???

Comment: I answered a question for you a month ago, still waiting to hear what happened there...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38955422/extract-value-form-xml

Comment: @chris85 thanks for answer i just found my own solution.

Comment: You could post your solution as an answer in that case. As is you have 3 unanswered/accepted questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $article = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec lectus urna, tempor nec dui eget, ullamcorper interdum ex. Sed velit velit, sodales non eros eu, porttitor ultricies risus. Morbi semper ultrices tortor non vestibulum. Vestibulum eu lorem odio. Duis placerat dapibus lorem sit amet viverra. Nam at sagittis augue, sit amet interdum metus. Curabitur quis diam pellentesque, auctor magna eget, cursus orci. Proin et fringilla mi. Vivamus egestas sed turpis vel scelerisque. Proin sit amet commodo urna, vel pulvinar lacus. Praesent tincidunt ut diam at interdum.';

  $words = explode(' ', $article);
                    // a new array to hold the string we are going to create
  $randId = rand(0, sizeOf($words));
  array_splice($words, $randId, 0, array('Random string in random place'));
  $newString = implode(',', $words);
  echo $newString; // Will print the new string
```

Comment: Thanks for share :) 

Any solution to dont explode HTML Tags? :)

Comment: Good question ! Right now no quick solution but will work on it. Implementation may be like this  - 1. Separate HTML tags from string and track the indexes  2. Then get the string contents and insert new content.  3. Implode

Answer (score 0):

`array_splice` get first argument by reference, so don't assign result to the same variable name `$newString`.

`array_splice($newString, $wstawwloowo, 0, $inserted);` it's enough.